# How to turn off Google auth check for Selenium test ("This device isn't recognized")

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, travis-ci, ui-automation, google-authentication

Currently I'm automating a web app, which has Google Authentication widget on login page. Technologies stack: Java, Selenium, ChromeDriver

I am trying to log in as a user with @gmail.com account. This account has no recovery phone and no recovery email set up. Nevertheless every time I am getting the following window during login attempt:

"Verify it's you

This device isn't recognized. For your security, Google wants to make sure it's really you"

with the following list of options:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaigM.png)

The problem is, that travis CI instance with test build is assigned to different locations. Each ChromeDriver instance I am using for log in is counted as a separate device. So, there is no "city I am usually signing in from"

Question: Is there a way to turn off ALL Google verifications for testing accounts? I actually tried to obtain SMSes for my test user, but Google does not deliver them in 120 seconds from time to time and it is very painful for builds stability

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to turn it off. But you could use a proxy.